# wiring a double light switch in bathroom

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, light

so i attempted  to install a vanity light which i did but as anticipated the wiring is mixed up or wrong. here we have the vanity light, the ceiling lights, the outlet next to the switch, and an outlet behind the wall. unfortunately, everything goes off and on when the lower switch is flipped. the upper switch controls the vanity light but only when the lower switch is in the "on" position. i would love for the outlet behind the wall, the outlet next to the switch and the vanity light to always have power.i can always leave the single switch instead of the double if thats better.can you help? thanks

original post: [How can I add a second light to my bathroom circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/187515/how-can-i-add-a-second-light-to-my-bathroom-circuit)

[image]
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emEXR.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Is one of the two switches inoperative?

Comment: no they all work fine but i would like everything to be hot independent of the switch

Answer (score 1):

First, check out some videos on good wire-on-screw technique.

Look carefully at the wires on the switch and be clear on their position.

Now, flip the switch over.

That should do it!

Comment: thanks for the comment. what do you mean flip the switch over?

Comment: I mean put the wires on the opposite side of where they are now.